# C++ error: no matching function for call, G++ compiler

Tags: c++

Good evening,

First of all I did search for question in topic, but unfortunately none of hints
and suggestion work for me. Simple code below:

```
random_device rd;   
mt19937 rng(rd());    
uniform_int_distribution<int> wspolrzedna(1, 19); 
uniform_int_distribution<int> kierunek(0, 3); 

class one {
    public: 
        int x, y, direction; 
        bool collision = false;

        one(int x, int y, int k):x(x),y(y),direction(k) {
        };
        one(){};
        ~one() {};

        void check(one& a){
            if((a.x==x) && (a.y==y)){
                a.collision =true;
                collision =true;
            }
        };
};

class two : public one {
    public: 
        int x,y,k,ms;   

        two(int x, int y, int k, int m):one(x,y,k),ms(m){                           
        };
        two(){};
        ~two() {};  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    vector<one*> tmp;

    tmp.push_back(new two(1, 2, 0,3)); 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        tmp.push_back(new one(wspolrzedna(rng),wspolrzedna(rng),kierunek(rng)));

    for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
        tmp[i]->check(tmp[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

In short, I want to compare x of one object (tmp[0]) with x of the other object (tmp[1] and tmp[2]). (and the same for y coordinate). 
Compiler (G++) error:

> g++ -std=gnu++11 stack.cpp -o stack

```
stack.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
stack.cpp:56:23: error: no matching function for call to 'one::check(one*&)'
tmp[i]->check(tmp[0]);
                   ^
stack.cpp:26:7: note: candidate: void one::check(one&)
void check(one& a){
   ^<p>
stack.cpp:26:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 
'__gnu_cxx::__al
loc_traits<std::allocator<one*> >::value_type {aka one*}' to 'one&'<p>
```

I have a default constructor and at the moment no clue how to fix this.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you can not read the error message?

Comment: Change `tmp[i]->check(tmp[0]);` by `tmp[i]->check(*(tmp[0]));`

Comment: Thanks. tmp[i]->check(*(tmp[0])); solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your vector contains pointers to `one`,

```
vector<one*> tmp;
```

but you try to call check, which takes a reference to one:

```
void check(one& a)
```

and the compiler tells you exactly that.

So, either you don't store pointers in `tmp`, or you derefence when calling `check`, or you make `check` accept pointers.